# json_normalize and multiple nested dictionaries (SOQL)

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a JSON file returned  from a SalesForce (SOQL) query like the following example and I want to use "json_normalize" to convert in a pandas dataFrame.

> with open('SOQL_RESULT.json') as data_file:
>     data = json.load(data_file)
>
> df = json_normalize(data)

**SOQL_RESULT.json**  file :

```
[
    {
        "attributes": {
            "type": "Opp_Product_Item__c",
            "url": "/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Opp_Product_Item__c/a0L40000007M7ViEAK"
        },
        "Id": "a0L40000007M7ViEAK",
        "Name": "OPI-273731",
        "Opportunity__c": "0064000000LlgMZAAZ",
        "Opportunity_Solution__c": "a0M400000038XGeEAM",
        "Product__c": "01t400000013pTyAAI",
        "Product_Sales_Team__r": {
            "totalSize": 3,
            "done": true,
            "records": [
                {
                    "attributes": {
                        "type": "Product_Sales_Team__c",
                        "url": "/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Product_Sales_Team__c/a0X40000001xZfLEAU"
                    },
                    "Id": "a0X40000001xZfLEAU",
                    "Name": "PIT-120844",
                    "Team_Role__c": "Specialist - CPS",
                    "Access__c": "Read/Write",
                    "Product__c": "a0L40000007M7ViEAK"
                },
                {
                    "attributes": {
                        "type": "Product_Sales_Team__c",
                        "url": "/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Product_Sales_Team__c/a0X40000001xZfQEAU"
                    },
                    "Id": "a0X40000001xZfQEAU",
                    "Name": "PIT-120845",
                    "Team_Role__c": "CSE",
                    "Access__c": "Read/Write",
                    "Product__c": "a0L40000007M7ViEAK"
                },
                {
                    "attributes": {
                        "type": "Product_Sales_Team__c",
                        "url": "/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Product_Sales_Team__c/a0X40000001xdkbEAA"
                    },
                    "Id": "a0X40000001xdkbEAA",
                    "Name": "PIT-121462",
                    "Team_Role__c": "CSE - Collaboration",
                    "Access__c": "Read",
                    "Product__c": "a0L40000007M7ViEAK"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "attributes": {
            "type": "Opp_Product_Item__c",
            "url": "/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Opp_Product_Item__c/a0L40000009fnUPEAY"
        },
        "Id": "a0L40000009fnUPEAY",
        "Name": "OPI-372996",
        "Opportunity__c": "0064000000QlQmsAAF",
        "Opportunity_Solution__c": "a0M40000004IyUqEAK",
        "Product__c": "01t400000013pTdAAI",
        "Product_Sales_Team__r": {
            "totalSize": 1,
            "done": true,
            "records": [
                {
                    "attributes": {
                        "type": "Product_Sales_Team__c",
                        "url": "/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Product_Sales_Team__c/a0X40000004N1LlEAK"
                    },
                    "Id": "a0X40000004N1LlEAK",
                    "Name": "PIT-150866",
                    "Team_Role__c": "CSE",
                    "Access__c": "Read/Write",
                    "Product__c": "a0L40000009fnUPEAY"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

But instead of having 1 row of nested data in the **Product_sales_team__.r.records column** like this :

```
Id    Name    Opportunity_Solution__c ... Product_Sales_Team__r.records
a...  OP...   a0M...                      [{'attributes': {'type': 'Product_Sales_Team__c', …
a...  OP...   a0M...                      [{'attributes': {'type': 'Product_Sales_Team__c', …
```

I want to add 3 new columns (Team_Role__c, Acces__c and Product__c )  with the data under Product_Sales_Team__r. records In the final dataFrame.

I tried with :

> ```
> df = json_normalize(data, 'Product_Sales_Team__r[records]', ['Id'], ['Name'], ['Opportunity__c'], 
>        record_prefix='Product_Sales_Team__r_records_Name')
> ```

But It did not work and based on Google  examples and the official "json_normalize" documentation I do not understand why ?

here is how the desired dataFrame should look like :

```
Id    Name    Opportunit...   Team_Role__c    Acces__c    Product__c
a1...  OP...   a0M...           A...           B...        P1...         
a1...  OP...   a0M...           A...           B...        P2...  
a1...  OP...   a0M...           A...           B...        P3...  
a2...  OP...   a0M...           A...           B...        P1...  
a2...  OP...   a0M...           A...           B...        P2...    
a2...  OP...   a0M...           A...           B...        P3...  
...
```

Any help would be appreciate!

Ken

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Pandas json\_normalize on nested Json with arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45418334/using-pandas-json-normalize-on-nested-json-with-arrays)

Comment: Have a look at the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45419878/3423035) from @pirsquared. This works for your data.