# How to flatten a nested JSON into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, json-normalize

I have a bit of a tricky `JSON` I want to put into a dataframe.

```json
{'A': {'name': 'A',
  'left_foot': [{'toes': '5'}],
  'right_foot': [{'toes': '4'}]},
 'B': {'name': 'B',
  'left_foot': [{'toes': '3'}],
  'right_foot': [{'toes': '5'}]},
...
}
```

I don't need the first layer with A and B as it is part of name.  There will always only be one left_foot and one right_foot.

The data I want is as follows:

```
     name  left_foot.toes right_foot.toes
0       A           5           4
1       B           3           5
```

Using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45418334/using-pandas-json-normalize-on-nested-json-with-arrays) is was able to get the feet and toes but that is if you say data["A"].  Is there an easier way?

**EDIT**
I have something like this, but I need to specify `"A"` in the first line.

```
df = pd.json_normalize(tickers["A"]).pipe(
    lambda x: x.drop('left_foot', 1).join(
        x.left_foot.apply(lambda y: pd.Series(merge(y)))
    )
).rename(columns={"toes": "left_foot.toes"}).pipe(
    lambda x: x.drop('right_foot', 1).join(
        x.right_foot.apply(lambda y: pd.Series(merge(y)))
    )).rename(columns={"toes": "right_foot.toes"})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Given your data, each top level `key` (e.g. `'A'` and `'B'`) is repeated as a `value` in `'name'`, therefore it will be easier to use `pandas.json_normalize` on only the `values` of the `dict`.
- The `'left_foot'` and `'right_foot'` columns need be exploded to remove each `dict` from the `list`
- The final step converts the columns of `dicts` to a dataframe and joins it back to `df`
- It's not necessarily less code, but this should be significantly faster than the multiple applies used in the current code.

  - See this [timing analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64563986/7758804) comparing `apply pandas.Series` to just using `pandas.DataFrame` to convert a column.
- If there are issues because your dataframe has `NaN` (e.g. missing `dicts` or `lists`) in the columns to be exploded and converted to a dataframe, see [How to json_normalize a column with NaNs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63876637/7758804)

```py
import pandas as pd

# test data
data = {'A': {'name': 'A', 'left_foot': [{'toes': '5'}], 'right_foot': [{'toes': '4'}]}, 'B': {'name': 'B', 'left_foot': [{'toes': '3'}], 'right_foot': [{'toes': '5'}]}, 'C': {'name': 'C', 'left_foot': [{'toes': '5'}], 'right_foot': [{'toes': '4'}]}, 'D': {'name': 'D', 'left_foot': [{'toes': '3'}], 'right_foot': [{'toes': '5'}]}}

# normalize data.values and explode the dicts out of the lists
df = pd.json_normalize(data.values()).apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index(drop=True)

# display(df)
  name      left_foot     right_foot
0    A  {'toes': '5'}  {'toes': '4'}
1    B  {'toes': '3'}  {'toes': '5'}
2    C  {'toes': '5'}  {'toes': '4'}
3    D  {'toes': '3'}  {'toes': '5'}

# extract the values from the dicts and create toe columns
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('left_foot').values.tolist())).rename(columns={'toes': 'lf_toes'})
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('right_foot').values.tolist())).rename(columns={'toes': 'rf_toes'})

# display(df)
  name lf_toes rf_toes
0    A       5       4
1    B       3       5
2    C       5       4
3    D       3       5
```

Comment: Spot on @trenton!  Worked like a charm! 100% what I needed!